# Show widget under accordion class only when user clicks on heading?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `accordion` like this which is working fine. The content of accordion is shown by default and when the user clicks on heading it goes away. What I want to do is, doesn't show the content at first when the page loads and shown and hide only when the user clicks on heading. How can I do that?

```
 <div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
        Video tags
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
       <table class="table table-bordered">  
        <thead>  
          <tr>  
            <th>Time Code</th>
            <th>Tag Name</th>  
          </tr>  
        </thead>  
        <tbody>  
        {% for i in "xxxxxxxxxx" %}

          <tr>  
            <td><input type="text" class="span2" name="time_code{{ forloop.counter }}" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="span2" name="tag_name{{ forloop.counter }}" /></td>  
           </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>  
      </table>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I created a working version with the style you need http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/utEb8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the following code:

```
 <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
```

remove the class **in**. this would hide your content by default